# Combining Greek and expression in ggplot2 output

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I know that if I use:
expression(paste(beta,1)) in the title of a ggplot2 I'll get the output:
β1.

Suppose that the number is generated by a loop so at the ith iteration evaluating:
text.test
gives i.
I want to get something like:
β_i
in the title of my ggplot2...how can I go about doing that since:
expression(paste(beta,text.test))
gives me
βtext.test (and not β_i)....

Comment: Do you mean you want an underscore, or you want to put the i in a subscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `bquote`

```
library(ggplot2)
text.test <- "i"
ggplot() +
    ggtitle(bquote(beta*"_"*.(text.test)))
```

[image]

---

If we need the `i` as a subscript

```
ggplot() + 
     ggtitle(bquote(beta[.(text.test)]))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!  This was sooo helpful! Thanks a giant ton akrun!!!  I wish I can up-vote it 300 times!! :D

Comment: Just one more related question... if I want to say something like: "parameter evolution β_2"  how could I modify the bquote bit?  paste doesn't seem to work :0

Comment: @CSA You can do `ggplot() +
    ggtitle(bquote("parameter evolution"~beta*"_"*.(text.test)))`